# Need to keep track of types of opencv Mats

Tags: c++, templates, macros, types, opencv

So I'm using the class `Mat` from opencv in a program I'm writing.  `Mat` looks something like this:

```
class Mat {
    public:
        Mat(int width, int height, int type);
        template <typename T> T getElt(int x, int y);
        int depth();
        ...
}
```

The type in the constructor specifies whether elements in the `Mat` are `float`s, `int`s, etc as well as the number of channels in the image.  `depth()` returns the data type used to store image elements.

Unfortunately I have to call `getElt()` in my code.  Whenever I do that I use a `switch` statement to check the depth of the `Mat` so I can call `getElt()` with the appropriate template parameter.  Doing it that way is pretty verbose, so I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.  Could I create a container for a `Mat` and use template magic create a method that returns a type as opposed to a value?  Or could I use macros to make things more efficient and logical?

I'd rather not have to subclass `Mat` since there are several methods besides `getElt()` for which I have this same issue.

Edit: made the description more accurate.

Comment: What happens if you call it with the "wrong" template parameter? Do you get garbage or does the result get converted to the requested type? If the latter, could you possibly always use double type?

Comment: That would not work: the docs say the type must match the actual matrix type.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `Mat_<T>` instead. An black&white image really isn't the same as a greyscale image, and neither is  equal to a color image. Those should be separate at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the 'type' in openCV MAT corresponds to the image type (ie number of channels) not the data type float/int/char etc.

If you want a templated image class that can transparently work with char/int/bool/double etc - take a look at [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I need to use other functionality provided by opencv that would be hard to write myself.

Comment: I thought so! Although CImg does have a lot of functionality - it's the best image lib if you need template image types.